# (REDSHIFT) Vertical Coalesce / FIRST_VALUE() as an Aggregate

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aggregation

*(This is Redshift specific and should account for it's columnar nature, sort order, etc.)*

I need to get the first non-NULL value from each column, by category, when sorted by a timestamp.

Essentially, the same as FIRST_VALUE() does, but as an aggregate.

Alternatively, a COALESCE() as an aggregate.

Redshift, however, doesn't have the niceties of later version of PostgreSQL or Oracle.  So, I'm seeking options to test on my 100 million row imports :)

*(I don't like either of my options, but I'm stumped for better ones.)*

Sample Input

```
 category | row_timestamp | value_a | value_b | value_c
----------+---------------+---------+---------+---------

    01    |      001      |   NULL  |   NULL  |     4
    01    |      010      |      7  |   NULL  |  NULL
    01    |      100      |   NULL  |      1  |     2
    01    |      999      |      6  |      3  |     6

    02    |      001      |      1  |   NULL  |  NULL
    02    |      010      |   NULL  |      2  |  NULL
    02    |      100      |   NULL  |      1  |     9
    02    |      999      |      6  |      3  |     2
```

Expected Results

```
 category |                 value_a | value_b | value_c
----------+-------------------------+---------+---------
    01    |                      7  |      1  |     4
    02    |                      1  |      2  |     9
```

Current solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    category,
    FIRST_VALUE(value_a IGNORE NULLS)
        OVER (PARTITION BY category
                  ORDER BY row_timestamp
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
             )
                 AS value_a,

    FIRST_VALUE(value_b IGNORE NULLS)
        OVER (PARTITION BY category
                  ORDER BY row_timestamp
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
             )
                 AS value_b,

    FIRST_VALUE(value_c IGNORE NULLS)
        OVER (PARTITION BY category
                  ORDER BY row_timestamp
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
             )
                 AS value_c
FROM
    mytable
```

It works, but the DISTINCT might apply over hundreds or thousands of rows.  Less than ideal.

If it was only for one or two columns, this might work *(but it's for a dozen columns, so it's horrible)*...

```
WITH
    sorted_value_a AS
(
    SELECT
        category,
        value_a,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category
                               ORDER BY value_a IS NOT NULL, row_timestamp
                          )
                              AS row_ordinal
    FROM
        myTable
),
    sorted_value_b AS
(
    SELECT
        category,
        value_b,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category
                               ORDER BY value_b IS NOT NULL, row_timestamp
                          )
                              AS row_ordinal
    FROM
        myTable
),
    sorted_value_c AS
(
    SELECT
        category,
        value_c,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category
                               ORDER BY value_c IS NOT NULL, row_timestamp
                          )
                              AS row_ordinal
    FROM
        myTable
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sorted_value_a   AS a
INNER JOIN
    sorted_value_b   AS b
        ON b.category = a.category
INNER JOIN
    sorted_value_c   AS c
        ON c.category = a.category
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this is as aesthetically pleasing, but you could do:

```
select category, value_a, value_b, value_c, value_d
from (select coalesce(value_a, lag(value_a ignore nulls) over (partition by category order by row_timestamp)) as value_a,
             coalesce(value_b, lag(value_b ignore nulls) over (partition by category order by row_timestamp)) as value_b,
             coalesce(value_c, lag(value_c ignore nulls) over (partition by category order by row_timestamp)) as value_c,
             coalesce(value_d, lag(value_d ignore nulls) over (partition by category order by row_timestamp)) as value_d
             row_number() over (partition by category order by row_timestamp desc) as seqnum 
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hopefully better than using `DISTINCT` to collapse it down.  Nice thought, thanks, I'll try it and let you know :)

Comment: Replacing `DISTINCT` with `ROW_NUMBER() = 1` gave significant savings, including a better execution plan for subsequent joins, etc.  As we happen to need a mix of `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` *(which I was unaware of at the time of my OP)*, I never did test the benefits of `FIRST_VALUE(this IGNORE NULLS)` vs `COALESCE(this, LAG(this IGNORE NULLS))`.